# progress bar loading is not working

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

I am try to run the progress bar in my frame but it is not working. I am tried to display the visible in my second java class but set visible(true) displaying it as error.
Hope you guys can help me to solve my problem/error

Displaying error in my second java class:
"Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:    The method 
    setvisible(boolean) is undefined for the type mgfinancewindow"

```
First java class: mgfinancewindow.java
package mgfinance;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class mgfinancewindow {
private JFrame frame;
public JProgressBar progressBar;
public JLabel lblNewLabel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mgfinancewindow window = new mgfinancewindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public mgfinancewindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("MG Finances");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1362, 705);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel_1.setBounds(0, 646, 1362, 59);
    panel.add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Loading...");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(1139, 0, 114, 34);
    panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

    progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setBackground(new Color(0, 51, 51));
    progressBar.setBounds(0, 34, 1362, 14);
    panel_1.add(progressBar);

    JLabel lblMgFinance = new JLabel("MG Finance");
    lblMgFinance.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblMgFinance.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));
    lblMgFinance.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    lblMgFinance.setBounds(0, 11, 1362, 635);
    panel.add(lblMgFinance);


}

}
```

second java class: progressbar.java

```
package mgfinance;


public class progress {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    mgfinancewindow load = new mgfinancewindow();
    for(int i=0; i<=100; i++){
        Thread.sleep(150);
        load.setvisible(true);
        load.lblNewLabel.setText("Loading..."+ i);
        load.progressBar.setValue(i);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mgfinancewindow` class is not a `JComponent` to support the `setVisible()` method itself. The `JFrame` inside it has the `setVisible` method.

In the way you wrote the code, to solve your problem quickly you must write the `frame.setVisible(true);` at the end (last statement) of `initialize()` method in `mgfinancewindow` class and remove `load.setvisible(true);` from the `main` method of `progress` class:

```
public class progress {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        mgfinancewindow load = new mgfinancewindow();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(150);
            //load.setvisible(true);
            load.lblNewLabel.setText("Loading..." + i);
            load.progressBar.setValue(i);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class mgfinancewindow {
    private JFrame frame;
    public JProgressBar progressBar;
    public JLabel lblNewLabel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mgfinancewindow window = new mgfinancewindow();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public mgfinancewindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("MG Finances");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1362, 705);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 646, 1362, 59);
        panel.add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Loading...");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(1139, 0, 114, 34);
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setBackground(new Color(0, 51, 51));
        progressBar.setBounds(0, 34, 1362, 14);
        panel_1.add(progressBar);

        JLabel lblMgFinance = new JLabel("MG Finance");
        lblMgFinance.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblMgFinance.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));
        lblMgFinance.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        lblMgFinance.setBounds(0, 11, 1362, 635);
        panel.add(lblMgFinance);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**But**:

When you are creating a component like `mgfinancewindow` which creates a `JFrame` inside, most of the times it's better to **extend** from `JFrame` and then you can create an object from it and call the `setVisible` method on it in the main method of your program or so. It's better not to call `setVisible` inside that component, because in another classes sometimes you want to create and initialize the `mgfinancewindow` but you don't want to make it visible immediately.

**Another hints**:

According to **Java Coding Conventions**:

1. Your class names must follow the *CamelCase* style.
2. Variable names must follow the *camelCase* (first letter in lower-case) style.

You may want to take a look at other java coding conventions [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Coding_Conventions).

Comment: @sharkrish: Your welcome. Hope this helps. In stackoverflow when an answer helps you or solves your problem, you may want to check the green check mark in the left of the answer to mark it as the answer.

Comment: But i still encounters the same problem. the progress Bar is not working . The progresbar is not running/loading displaying 0%

Comment: It's because you are running the wrong `main` method in the `mgfinancewindow` class. You should run the main method in the `progress` class.

Comment: Can you please send me the edited working code. Hope you will help me

Comment: I've added the code, don't forget to run the main method of `progress` class.

Comment: @sharkrish: completely remove the `main` method of the `mgfinancewindow` class and try again. Here your code is working when I run the `progress` class and it shows the progress bar without a fault, it's getting filled normally up to 100%